# Bootstrap Carousel slideshow doesn't scroll through more than three slides

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I can't make my slideshow automatically scroll through all of my pictures. It scrolls through three pictures, but I have six. When I click on the arrows, it scrolls through all of the pictures, but it doesn't scroll through all of the pictures automatically. It works when the site isn't live, but it doesn't work in Chrome when it is live. Here is my code..

```
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel-inner" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active">
                <img src="img/landscape.jpg" alt="landscape design and installation">
                <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                </div>      

            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/patio.jpg" alt="stonework">
            <div class="carousel-caption"></div>    
            </div>  

        <div class="item">
        <img src="img/patio2.jpg" alt="full-service">
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>  

    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/firepit.png" alt="Fire Pit">
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>  

    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/deck.png" alt="deck">
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>  

    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/gardens.png" alt="deck">
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>      

    </div>  

    <!-- Controls -->

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>

        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide fiddle please

Answer (score 5):

You need to add more data-targets:

```
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
```

Since you have 6 slides you need to to have 6 data targets (starting with 0)